# Function to print data type to debug console

Tags: c++, winapi

While searching for any kind of function in could help printing data to debug console, I've found this function here on `StackOverflow` that can print almost any kind of data:

```cpp
template <typename Arg, typename... Args>
void doPrint(Arg&& arg, Args&&... args)
{
    std::stringstream out;

    out << std::forward<Arg>(arg);
    using expander = int[];
    (void)expander {
        0, (void(out << std::left << std::setw(20) << std::forward<Args>(args)), 0)...
    };

    OutputDebugStringA(out.str().c_str());
}
```

But it doesn't work when I try to pass a `wstring` to it, ex:

```cpp
std::wstring color = L"blue";
doPrint("color: ", color);
```

I get this error:

```
Error    C2679    binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::wstring' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Is it possible to also support `wstring`?

I tried to change `std::stringstream` to `std::wstringstream`, but now I get error on `OutputDebugStringA()`:

```
void OutputDebugStringA(LPCSTR)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t>>' to 'LPCSTR'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, you can't print a `std::wstring` to a `char`-based `std::ostream`, such as `std::stringstream`, because `std::basic_ostream<char>` (aka `std::ostream`) does not have an overloaded `operator<<` defined for `std::wstring` (or `const wchar_t*`).

You could define your own `operator<<` for that purpose, which converts a `std::wstring` to a `std::string`/`char*` using `WideCharToMultiByte()` or equivalent conversion, and then print that instead, eg:

```cpp
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const std::wstring &wstr)
{
    int len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, wstr.c_str(), wstr.size(), nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr);
    if (len > 0) {
        std::string str;
        str.resize(len);
        WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, wstr.c_str(), wstr.size(), str.data()/* or: &str[0] */, len, nullptr, nullptr);
        os << str;
    }
    return os;
}

template <typename Arg, typename... Args>
void doPrint(Arg&& arg, Args&&... args)
{
    std::stringstream out;

    out << std::forward<Arg>(arg);
    using expander = int[];
    (void)expander {
        0, (void(out << std::left << std::setw(20) << std::forward<Args>(args)), 0)...
    };

    OutputDebugStringA(out.str().c_str());
}
```

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/UZBMD2Lqu)

Otherwise, you need a `wchar_t`-based `std::basic_ostream<wchar_t>` (aka `std::wostream`) instead, such as `std::wstringstream`, using `OutputDebugStringW()` for the logging (unless you convert the output `std::wstring` to `std::string` to log with `OutputDebugStringA()`).  Fortunately, `std::basic_ostream<CharT>` *does* have an overloaded `operator<<` for `const char*` strings (but not `std::string`) regardless of whether `CharT` is `char` or `wchar_t`, so `std::wstringstream` can print the pointer returned by `std::string::c_str()`, eg:

```cpp
std::wostream& operator<<(std::wostream &os, const std::string &str)
{
    os << str.c_str();
    return os;
}

template <typename Arg, typename... Args>
void doPrint(Arg&& arg, Args&&... args)
{
    std::wostringstream out;

    out << std::forward<Arg>(arg);

    using expander = int[];
    (void)expander {
        0, (void(out << std::left << std::setw(20) << std::forward<Args>(args)), 0)...
    };

    OutputDebugStringW(out.str().c_str());
}
```

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/nR5dhu9seD)

Comment: I'm getting some errors, In the first example: `argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPSTR"` and in the second example,  `identifier "arg" is undefined`

Comment: The "incompatible" error is because you are using an version of C++ that predates C++17, where `std::string::data()` is overloaded to return a non-const `char*`. In which case, you can use `&str[0]` instead.  The "identifier undefined" error was a typo on my part, I have fixed it.

Comment: Remy, how do I declare the template `doPrint` into the `.h` file to be able to access it in others `.cpp` files? I have tried adding into the `.h`: `template <typename Arg, typename... Args>`
`void doPrint(Arg&& arg, Args&&... args);` but i got compile errors: `Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl doPrint<char const (&)[14],int &>(char const (&)[14],int &)" (??$doPrint@AEAY0O@$$`

Comment: @Katia see [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/)

Comment: I read it but im more confuse than before, i tried now: `template <typename Arg, typename... Args>
struct test 
{
 void doPrint(Arg&& arg, Args&&... args);
}`

Comment: @Katia you can't *declare* a template in a header file and then *define* it in a .cpp file. Templates don't work that way. That is why you are getting "unresolved external" errors and such. The template has to be *defined* inside the same translation unit that *declares* it. You *can* separate the declaration and definition, as long as they are compiled together in the same translation unit, ie they exist in the same header file, or the definition is in a separate file that is `#include`'d by the header file. Otherwise, the template should be *declared* and *defined* as an inline function.